# Logitech LX5 cordless mouse freezes unexpectedly and green light always turned on

Tags: hardware-failure, logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech LX5 cordless mouse used for more than 2 years, nice mouse.

But recently, I have seen a strange behavior of the mouse, sometimes in the middle of my work. The mouse just stop moving, and the battery indicator on the top gives a green light for a long time. I need to press the `reset` button at the bottom of the mouse, but this only solve the problem for a little while, within 5 minutes, the mouse freezes and the green light turns on again. I have tried to change the battery, but it only solve the problem for a day, on the next day, the problem comes back, even I am using new batteries.

I have searched the manual and found that red light, rather than green light should be on if the battery is low, and green light should only turns on for a short while when the mouse the turned on.

I have searched the logitech site and found someone reporting a similar problem at [here](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Trackballs/Problem-with-logitech-lx5-mouse/td-p/432973), but there's no reply yet.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't another device running on the same frequency that may be interfering with the signal. It's even possible for a neighbor to have a Logitech mouse on the same frequency, I have experienced a similar problem. Also, make sure you have the latest version of Setpoint installed and then tell us if you still experience the issue.One more thing, the receiver needs to be as close to the mouse as possible. Desktop computers often have trouble transmitting the signal from under a large desk (another problem I have had).

Comment: talking about interference, will a new mouse (those using 2.4GHz frequency) solve the problem?

Comment: A lot of devices use that frequency (phones for example). It's hard to say, but mice are really cheap nowadays so it may be less hassle just to buy a new one. Get a logitech of course :). I always find that if you buy logitech wireless devices you can mix and match with what keyboard and mouse combo you want to use.